why unet forward takes whole GPU memory in every denoising loop
trying to write some toy example code of stable diffusion denoising without diffuser lib.
in diffusers examples :
https://huggingface.co/docs/diffusers/stable_diffusion
we just use the pipe style to run a base txt2image task like:
image = pipeline(prompt, generator=generator).images[0]
when I try to write my own example of the pipeline, like, tokenize txt, clip encoder, latents and denoising loop like:
import ...

base_model_path = "runwayml/stable-diffusion-v1-5"
vae_model_path = "stabilityai/sd-vae-ft-mse"
device = "cuda"
weight_dtype = torch.float16
    

def main():
    noise_scheduler = DDIMScheduler(
        num_train_timesteps=1000,
        beta_start=0.00085,
        beta_end=0.012,
        beta_schedule="scaled_linear",
        clip_sample=False,
        set_alpha_to_one=False,
        steps_offset=1,
    )
    tokenizer = CLIPTokenizer.from_pretrained(base_model_path, subfolder="tokenizer")
    vae = AutoencoderKL.from_pretrained(vae_model_path).to(dtype=torch.float16).to(device,dtype=weight_dtype)
    unet = UNet2DConditionModel.from_pretrained(base_model_path, subfolder="unet").to(device,dtype=weight_dtype)
    text_encoder = CLIPTextModel.from_pretrained(base_model_path, subfolder="text_encoder").to(device,dtype=weight_dtype)

    # pipe = StableDiffusionPipeline.from_pretrained(
    #     base_model_path,
    #     torch_dtype=torch.float16,
    #     scheduler=noise_scheduler,
    #     vae=vae,
    #     feature_extractor=None,
    #     safety_checker=None
    # )
    # pipe.text_encoder.to(device)

    generator = get_generator(seed=42, device=device)


    prompt = "An image of a squirrel in Picasso style"
    negative_prompt = ""

    text_input_ids = tokenizer(
            prompt,
            max_length=tokenizer.model_max_length,
            padding="max_length",
            truncation=True,
            return_tensors="pt"
        ).input_ids

    prompt_embeds_ = text_encoder(text_input_ids.to(device))[0].to(dtype=weight_dtype, device=device)

    # do cfg
    uncond_tokens = [negative_prompt]
    neg_text_input_ids = tokenizer(
            uncond_tokens,
            max_length=tokenizer.model_max_length,
            padding="max_length",
            truncation=True,
            return_tensors="pt"
        ).input_ids
    neg_prompt_embeds_ = text_encoder(neg_text_input_ids.to(device))[0].to(dtype=weight_dtype, device=device)

    prompt_embeds = torch.cat([neg_prompt_embeds_, prompt_embeds_])

    # # 5. Prepare timesteps
    noise_scheduler.set_timesteps(10)
    timesteps = noise_scheduler.timesteps

     # # 6. Prepare latent variables
    generator = get_generator(seed=42, device=device)
    latents = prepare_latents(
            1,
            4,
            512,
            512,
            torch.float16,
            device,
            generator,
    )

    for i, t in enumerate(timesteps):
        # do cfg
        latent_model_input = torch.cat([latents] * 2) 
        latent_model_input = noise_scheduler.scale_model_input(latent_model_input, t)

        noise_pred = unet(
                    latent_model_input,
                    t,
                    encoder_hidden_states=prompt_embeds,
                    return_dict=False,
        )[0]

        # perform guidance
        # if do_classifier_free_guidance:
        noise_pred_uncond, noise_pred_text = noise_pred.chunk(2)
        noise_pred = noise_pred_uncond + 7.5 * (noise_pred_text - noise_pred_uncond)

        latents = noise_scheduler.step(noise_pred, t, latents,  return_dict=False)[0]

    latents = latents.detach()
    with torch.no_grad():
        image = vae.decode(latents / vae.config.scaling_factor, return_dict=False)[0]

        vae_image_processor = image_processor.VaeImageProcessor(vae_scale_factor=vae.config.scaling_factor, do_convert_rgb=True)
        images = vae_image_processor.postprocess(image, output_type='pil', do_denormalize=[True])

        images[0].show()


calling unet forward takes around 4G of the GPU memory in every loop. I run num steps for 25 would OOM my GPU. witch is obvious no way in diffuser pipe code. Any idea?
for i, t in enumerate(timesteps):
noise_pred = unet(
                    latent_model_input,
                    t,
                    encoder_hidden_states=prompt_embeds,
                    return_dict=False,
        )[0] 

